# Error with php and mysql, constant == variable returns false even tho they are the same

Tags: php, mysql

Okay so I am really really confused right now, the php script successful prints the user data, however when validating against the data submitted the script will return an error. For example when

```
if ($uname = $checkuname){
```

It will return the else function, if I set it to

```
if ($uname = $uname){
```

it will successfully do that but return an error on the password. Could someone please help me and tell me what I am doing wrong

Also how would I hash and salt a password the same way they were done in the database. Thank you :)

```
$uname = "username";
$pwrd = "c2c1e68b386e1f9087dd0b8ff1334a56573cef54";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($server, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$sql = "SELECT id_group, member_name, passwd FROM smfrh_members WHERE member_name = '$uname'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["id_group"]. " - Name: " . $row["member_name"]. " " . $row["passwd"]. "<br>";
        print $uname;
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$checkuname = $row["member_name"];
$checkpwrd = $row["passwd"];
$checkgroup = $row["id_group"];


if ($uname == $checkuname){


if ($pwrd == $checkpwrd){



if ($checkgroup == "9"){
 echo "success"; 

} else {
if ($checkgroup == "1"){

echo "OMG An ADMIN!";


} else {
echo "Sorry you are not a premium member";

}


}

} else {

echo "Your password was incorrect";


}

}


else{

echo "Your username could not be found";
}


$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: `=` is used for assignment. You need to use `==` for comparison. ie `if($uname == $checkname){...}`

Comment: please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You have to hash the password the same way it was hashed when you stored it on the database. You should be using `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` to do this. [Link to the manual, make it your friend](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

Comment: @ImClarky Thanks so much I can't believe I forgot that, however it still isn't working

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thank you :) the forum program hashed it so I'll need to work it out :P thank you tho

Comment: In that case the Forum suite should provide a function you can use to hash the password

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to assign variables with an array that doesn't exist anymore, and therefore your variables: `$checkuname`, `$checkpwd` and `$checkgroup` are all set to `null`.

```
$checkuname = $row["member_name"];
$checkpwrd = $row["passwd"];
$checkgroup = $row["id_group"];
```

The `$row` array was created within the `while` loop `while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())`, and is only then accessible within that loop. You are then trying to access `$row` later on.

As, in theory, you are only expecting 1 row back - as it is a username / password situation - you can move the above assignments into the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this will work, in the if statement always use == instead of =

"==" means the check for exact the same like "42" == "42"

"=" means the check for the same data like "42" = 42

```js
//Set variables
$uname = "username";
$pwrd = "c2c1e68b386e1f9087dd0b8ff1334a56573cef54";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($server, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

//Declare SQL statement
$sql = "SELECT id_group, member_name, passwd FROM smfrh_members WHERE member_name = '$uname'";

//Catch result
$result = $conn->query($sql);

//Check for result
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["id_group"]. " - Name: " . $row["member_name"]. " " .          $row["passwd"]. "<br>";
        print $uname;
    }
} else echo "0 results";

//Put result into variables
$checkuname = $row["member_name"];
$checkpwrd = $row["passwd"];
$checkgroup = $row["id_group"];


if ($uname == $checkuname && $pwrd == $checkpwrd){

  if ($checkgroup = "9") echo "success"; 
  else if ($checkgroup = "1") echo "OMG An ADMIN!";
  else echo "Sorry you are not a premium member";

}

if ($uname != $checkuname) echo "Your username could not be found";
if ($pwrd != $checkpwrd) echo "Your password was incorrect";

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: I receive this reply: Your username could not be foundYour password was incorrect. Thank you tho :)

Comment: before you close the $conn you can checkup the data you have and you get try like: echo $uname .":". $checkuname." ".$pwrd.":".$checkpwrd;

Comment: this will leave something like: username:requestedusername c2c1e68b386e1f9087dd0b8ff1334a56573cef54:requestedpassword

Comment: ($checkgroup = "9") That needs to be ==, I have done that and it comes up the same.

Answer (score 0):

Solution, I defined the $check* before in the script.

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($server, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

//Declare SQL statement
$sql = "SELECT id_group, member_name, passwd FROM smfrh_members WHERE member_name = '$uname'";

//Catch result
$result = $conn->query($sql);

//Check for result
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

$checkuname = $row["member_name"];
$checkpwrd = $row["passwd"];
$checkgroup = $row["id_group"];


        echo "id: " . $checkgroup. " - Name: " . $checkuname. " " . $checkpwrd . "<br>";

    }
} else echo "0 results";

//Put result into variables


if ($uname == $checkuname && $pwrd == $checkpwrd){

  if ($checkgroup == "9") echo "success"; 
  else if ($checkgroup == "1") echo "OMG An ADMIN!";
  else echo "Sorry you are not a premium member";

}

if ($uname != $checkuname) echo "Your username could not be found";
if ($pwrd != $checkpwrd) echo "Your password was incorrect";

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Check my answer for an understanding as to *why* moving the `$check*` assignments worked.